# for/while loop memory clearing in C

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

In my program I'm messing around with, it simply asks for how many tests one has written and then returns an average. However I've modified it a bit so that it asks if the marks entered are correct.

Problem 1: It doesn't let you input your marks for all your tests
Problem 2: If the marks are wrong it starts over but keep the previous inputs in it's memory? How do I fix the?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //int variables for grade
    unsigned int counter; //number of grades to be entered next
    int grade;
    int total;
    float average;
    // user input
    int userInput; // amount of tests
    int yesNo; 
    //amount of test passed
    unsigned int pass = 0;
    unsigned int fail = 0;
    int doCount = 1;
    //unsigned int test;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------// 

    //standards for program to abide to
    total = 0; //Total amount of test to be set to zero, until while statement
    counter = 1; //Loop counter to start from one

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------// 

    printf ("Please enter amount of test you've written so far: ");
    scanf ("%d", &userInput);
    //printf ("%d", userInput);

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    do {
        //Body of calculations of program
        for(counter = 0; counter <= userInput; ++counter) { //for loop that correlates to userInput for amount of passes and test marks
            printf ("Please enter percentage mark: "); //prompt for test mark
            scanf("%d", &grade);
            total = total + grade;
            counter = counter + 1;
            if (grade >= 40) {  //if statement for pass or fail
               pass = pass + 1;
            } else {
                 fail = fail + 1;
                }
        }//end of for loop
        printf ("Are the grades entered correct? (1 = yes, 2 = no): "); // user input for yesNo - are inputs correct    
        scanf ("%d", &yesNo);
        if (yesNo == 2) {

         } else {
            average = ((float)total / userInput); //Getting average for tests so far
                //if statement to clarify if you're passing
            if (average < 40) {
                printf ("\nYou are below sub minimum!\n");
                printf ("Your overall average is: %.2f %\n", average);
                printf ("Passed: %d\n", pass);
                printf ("Failed: %d", fail);
            } else if (average >= 75){
                printf ("\nYou have a distinction agregate!\n");
                printf ("Your overall average is: %.2f %\n", average);
                printf ("Passed: %d\n", pass);
                printf ("Failed: %d", fail);
            } else {
                printf ("\nYour overall average is: %.2f %\n", average);
                printf ("Passed: %d\n", pass);
                printf ("Failed: %d", fail);
            }
        doCount = 2;    
        }
    } while (doCount == 1);

    average = ((float)total / userInput); //Getting average for tests so far
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//     

    getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that your loop `for(counter = 0; counter <= userInput; ++counter)` is dubious.  Normally, you'll either use `for (counter = 0; counter < maximum; ++counter)` or occasionally `for (counter = 1; counter <= maximum; ++counter)`.  Your loop iterates `userInput+1` times. (Think about it; the user enters 3 as `userInput`; the loop sets `counter` to 0, 1, 2, 3.  That's one more loop than the number the user said.)  Remember that arrays index from 0 in C; that's why the first alternative is used most often in C.

Comment: your code fails to compile cleanly.  as posted, it causes the compiler to output 7 warnings.  Strongly suggest always enable all warnings when compiling.  Then fix the warnings.  Amongst other things, there is no prototype for 'getch()' , which is not a portable system function.  suggest using 'getchar()' instead.

Comment: this line: 'if (average < 40) {' and this line: '} else if (average >= 75){'is comparing a float to a integer.  suggest using: 'if (average < 40.f) {' so it is comparing a float to a float.  Similarily '} else if (average >= 75.f){'

Comment: when calling the system function: 'scanf()' always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: 'printf ("Failed: %d", fail);' will not be output/displayed immediately suggest changing to: 'printf ("Failed: %d\n", fail);'  Note the additional '\n' at the end of the format string.

Comment: when the user is ask if the grades are correct, what happens when the user just enters a newline or 'n' or 'no' or 'yes'?   suggest placing the related scanf() in a loop that keeps asking until the user enters a valid value

Comment: to avoid having leftover values in the variables, just set those variables to 0 or 0.f to recover from the error

Comment: the question passed to the user: '"Are the grades entered correct? (1 = yes, 2 = no): "' is being used, when the user enters 1, to display stats about the grade average AND terminate the program.   When the user enters 2, the program continues trying to get more grades.  Suggest, when user enters 2 to insert code to clear the key variables so the grades can be entered again

Answer (score 2):

In your do while loop, when you come around for your second pass you need to reset your variables. Specifically the total variable should be reset to zero. You do it for the first time outside the do while loop but once it's in the loop for the second pass it doesn't get reset to 0. 
As for not reading all test inputs, if it asks for 9 but you need 10 then it likely is a problem with the for loop. I typically use counter++ and not ++counter as it increments the counter after the operation and not before the operation. That may or may not be the reason as I did not run your code, but it is worth looking at.

Comment: Also just as Viktor pointed out below counter = counter + 1 is not needed. The reason is the for loop does it for you Ie counter++. You might of experienced the effect of skipping every other test as a result of this. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your code and commented the changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //int variables for grade
    unsigned int counter; //number of grades to be entered next
    int grade;
    int total;
    float average;
    // user input
    int userInput; // amount of tests
    int yesNo;
    //amount of test passed
    unsigned int pass = 0;
    unsigned int fail = 0;
    int doCount = 1;
    //unsigned int test;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------// 

    //standards for program to abide to
    total = 0; //Total amount of test to be set to zero, until while statement
    counter = 0; //Loop counter to start from zero, It's always better to start from zero

                 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------// 

    printf("Please enter amount of test you've written so far: ");
    scanf("%d", &userInput);
    //printf ("%d", userInput);

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    do {
        //Body of calculations of program
        total = 0; //You need to reset total pass and fail
        pass = 0;
        fail = 0;
        for (counter = 0; counter < userInput; ++counter) { //for loop that correlates to userInput for amount of passes and test marks
            printf("Please enter percentage mark: "); //prompt for test mark
            scanf("%d", &grade);
            total = total + grade;
            //counter = counter + 1; You DON't need that
            if (grade >= 40) {  //if statement for pass or fail
                pass = pass + 1;
            }
            else {
                fail = fail + 1;
            }
        }//end of for loop
        printf("Are the grades entered correct? (1 = yes, 2 = no): "); // user input for yesNo - are inputs correct    
        scanf("%d", &yesNo);
        if (yesNo == 2) {

        }
        else {
            average = ((float)total / userInput); //Getting average for tests so far
                                                  //if statement to clarify if you're passing
            if (average < 40) {
                printf("\nYou are below sub minimum!\n");
                printf("Your overall average is: %.2f %\n", average);
                printf("Passed: %d\n", pass);
                printf("Failed: %d", fail);
            }
            else if (average >= 75) {
                printf("\nYou have a distinction agregate!\n");
                printf("Your overall average is: %.2f %\n", average);
                printf("Passed: %d\n", pass);
                printf("Failed: %d", fail);
            }
            else {
                printf("\nYour overall average is: %.2f %\n", average);
                printf("Passed: %d\n", pass);
                printf("Failed: %d", fail);
            }
            doCount = 2;
        }
    } while (doCount == 1);

    average = ((float)total / userInput); //Getting average for tests so far
                                          //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//     

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! much appreciated